# jQuery UI Datepicker after select/change month/year

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I wanted to find out how I can run some piece of code (attach mouseenter event) for every day after user has selected a day or changed a month/year?

I have tried to attach the event on these events

- beforeShow
- beforeShowDay
- onChangeMonthYear
- onSelect

On hover I want to highlight next day in the same row if it exists.

Currently I attach moouseenter/mouseleave event to all days after datepicker is created (which is inline).

I have simplified what I'm doing in the JS fiddle below. I need to have those events working after a date is selected and after month/year has been changed.

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MartinTale/Xx4GS/2/

```
$("div").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    inline: true,
    altField: "#datep"
});

$("tbody td:not(.ui-state-disabled, .active-calendar-cell)").mouseenter(function (e) {
    $(this).closest('td').next().find("a").addClass("hover-calendar-cell");    
    console.log('test');
});

$("tbody td:not(.ui-state-disabled)").mouseleave(function (e) {
    $("a.hover-calendar-cell").removeClass("hover-calendar-cell");
    console.log('test out');
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the doc you can easily find an event provided bu Jquery Datepicker : onChangeMonthYear.

Comment: Updated the question and created a JS Fiddle. I have tried onChangeMonthYear already.

Comment: I see in the fiddle you want to do something more in hover; can you expand a bit what your needs are ?

Comment: On hover I want to highlight next day in the same row if it exists.

Comment: It already does that, just not once you've selected a date. Is that the issue?

Comment: @RudiVisser Yes, exactly! I need it to work right after a different date is selected or month/year changed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is hacky hack.

http://jsfiddle.net/Xx4GS/3/

It works, highlights the next day( the next `td` in this case).

setTimeout is because I think jquery ui destroys the active date item, so we wait until we have the right one.

You might be able to use `onSelect` instead of `.change`, but not a big deal imo

I left a console.log in there so you can see a little bit of whats going on.

Comment: This helped a lot and steered me in the right direction. Thank you. Result for the simplified version: http://jsfiddle.net/MartinTale/Xx4GS/4/

Answer (score 16):

You can use the provided jQuery datepicker events [`onSelect`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect) and [`onChangeMonthYear`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onChangeMonthYear).

Code:

```
$("#datep").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    onSelect: function () {
        console.log('s');
    },
    onChangeMonthYear: function () {
        console.log('o');
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/Xx4GS/

Answer (score 1):

There is an event called "onSelect" having the date as its param. see this example:

```
$("#datePicker").datepicker({
    //the format
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    //called when date is selected
    onSelect: function (date) {
        alert(date);
    }
});
```

Cou can find all the details in the api-doc: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect