# jquery-date-range-picker cant get a onMonthChange Event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the jQuery Date Range Picker to present a calendar to the user.
I need to display the dates based on some values from the server.
But I need to fetch the data whenever the "next" button is clicked (month is changed) as opposed to before displaying a single date.

[image]

I checked on the [API](http://longbill.github.io/jquery-date-range-picker/) but there doesn't seem to be any method defined that handles changes in months.

Answer (score 0):

you need to handle this on change event , on click on month , you call server and get the date and display on the screen.

[check this post for change event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23951428/jquery-ui-datepicker-after-select-change-month-year)

Comment: The above post refers to the [Jquery Datepicker](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/).I am using [jQuery Date Range Picker](https://longbill.github.io/jquery-date-range-picker/) and it doesnt seem to support onMonthChange events

Comment: but all you need to do is, you have to handle this in your event handler.. you can take this as an reference

Comment: Like I said in my question, it doesnt seem to be firing any events when you change Month....some example code would help